# Glide ModelLoader - Need to get image url from network on the fly

Tags: android, android-glide

**Goal:**
I have a List of model which is rendered inside a recyclerview where I am loading images with glide. 
My Model and Model.imageUrl comes from two different sources (which I have no control over). So for each model I need to call model.getImageUrl() which is a network call. 
So what I want to achieve here is recyclerviewAdapter.onBindViewHolder will call Glide...load(model) and that'll trigger my model.getImageUrl() and the image will be loaded by glide after model.getImageUrl() is done.

**Research so far:**
As I understand I need to implement a the ModelLoader as explained here: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/tut/custom-modelloader.html

I have tried using BaseGlideUrlLoader but calling model.getImageUrl() inside BaseGlideUrlLoader.getUrl() causes a policy violation (probably due to network call on main thread) since all the network requests should be done inside DataFetcher.loadData() method.

I have tried looking into DataFetcher implementations here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/search?p=2&q=implements+DataFetcher&unscoped_q=implements+DataFetcher

but I don't know which one to follow. Also I don't want to change how glide loads imageUrls to imageViews overall so I want to write DataFetcher.loadData() in a way it does not change Glide image loading logic.

I am still confused and can't seem to get a start on this. **A bit of sample code that achieves my goal would be highly appreciated** as I've been struggling with this for a week now.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getImageUrl(callback: (String) -> Unit) {
//GET IMAGE URL AND RETURN IT WITH 
callback(imageUrl)
}
```

Then in your onBind method call

```
getImageUrl {
//LOAD IMAGE WITH GLIDE. THE URL WILL BE CALLED ‘it’ AS BELOW
Glide.with(this).load(it).into(imageView)
}
```

Comment: That was a bit confusing for me, could you be a little more detailed?

Comment: Really not too sure how I can be more specific than giving you the exact code that you need....which part is confusing you, I’ll try explain it a little better.

Comment: 1. fun getImageUrl is method called on main thread or network, if so how should I call it?

Comment: @androidgotchas19 getImageUrl is just an example method. Where it says //GET IMAGE URL AND RETURN IT is where you put your code that currently fetches the imageUrl, whichever thread that is on is up to you. If you'd like to put a sample projection on GitHub I can create PR for you that addresses this.